# SQLite & Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there any tool/eclipse plugin to see the database tablets visually without using sqlite3 from the console/shell?

I've seen in threads like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149438/tool-to-see-android-database-tables-and-data that you can use sqlite database browser... but for that you need to  "pull the file from device".

I would like a method to see them in "real-time" without needing to copy the file from the emulator, and visually, with a tool like SQL Developer for SQLite.

Any ideias?

Is it even possible at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for a tool like this a while. The only thing i found is [questoid](http://www.questoid.com/Tools/QuestoidDevTools.aspx). Which is commercial. But it seems to be exactly what you are searching for.

Comment: Nothing free for commercial use out there?

Comment: unfortunatly not (regarding to my searches right now). I was searching a few hours for that. I don't know how hard your pain is without such a tool. I decided that i will pull down the file etc.. rather then paying $29. I just couldn't find a free one.

Comment: Mhm... i will have a look at the extension points of the ADT maybe its easy to implement a mini plugin which just pulls down the file, opens it in external browser and uploads again after editing.

Comment: I'll be watching out for any other suggestion free software for that that is eventually talked about here. Anyway thanks for the help and fast answer!!

Answer (score 1):

I use a solution similar to this one, http://goo.gl/sPgKQ, to copy my database to my sd card. Then I use the SQLite manager add-on, http://goo.gl/qfL7P,  for Firefox.

The only method I've seen to view the database in real time involves either rooting your phone or having a developer device. Otherwise you don't have the permissions necessary to access the data/ directory on your device. The above solution was the most efficient way I could find (without paying for anything). Though I am open to a better way.

Comment: And if you have a rooted/developer phone what solutions have you seen?

Comment: You can use a shell via ADB to explore your device. The shell comes with some basic commands (though much less than a standard terminal in Linux) and it has sqlite3 installed, so you can view or manipulate a specified database (found in /data/data/provider.your.looking.for/databases).

Comment: Hum k. I knew that was possible i was thinking that you were referring to a more polished way.. something with visual interface :-)

Comment: Ah, nope. I wish I had a better way.